# How to display information from API?

Tags: php, api

I'm trying to shorten long URLs from my web app using the FFS.Im API, but I don't know how.

`$url = 'http://localhost/notepad/view.php?f='.$_GET['f'];`

```
function shorten($url) {
  $call = file_get_contents('http://api.ffs.im/?url=' . $url);
  $call = json_decode($call, true);
  if( $call['result'] !== 0 ) {
    return $call['result'];
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I tried doing `<?php echo $call['result']; ?>` but it wasn't displaying anything.

And no, it's not because I'm trying to shorten localhost because that works fine if I do it manually.

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

http://ffs.im/api.html Here's their API reference.

Comment: Have you tried it? It is working for me

Comment: I have also check it. it works for me both way. Can you try to on the notice may be any then solve it

Comment: This has been fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a function therefore you have to call it after the declaration

```
function shorten($url) {
  $call = file_get_contents('http://api.ffs.im/?url=' . $url);
  $call = json_decode($call, true);
  if( $call['result'] !== 0 ) {
    return $call['result'];
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
$url = 'http://localhost/notepad/view.php?f='.$_GET['f'];

echo shorten($url);
```

Comment: I don't think you need to declare function first. you can declare function anywhere.

Comment: Doesn't matter. I load all of my php first then go into HTML and call what I need.

Comment: @bansi I just showed him an example. It could be a best practice as separating functions from logic. Correct me If I am wrong.